# Using a VS2005 string implentation in VS2017

Tags: string, class, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2005

I am reversing a very old game from 2005 which uses a different `basic_string` class from vs2017.

I have almost finished my project but I'm stuck one this part:

```
accessing string/wstring objects
```

I know how to retrieve the objects from the game process. The problem comes from the string class that has a different size and structure in vs2005+ compiled games.

Is there any way I can access those strings without having to convert my project into a vs2005 solution or rewriting the class from scratch?